# How to inline a goal with findall/3, (use just one predicate)?

Tags: list, prolog, tuples, prolog-findall

I have a knowledgebase that looks something like this

```
fact1(1, _, a, _, _).
fact1(2, _, c, _, _).
fact1(3, _, d, _, _).
fact1(4, _, f, _, _).

fact2(_, 1, b, _, _).
fact2(_, 2, c, _, _).
fact2(_, 4, e, _, _).
```

For every `fact1` & `fact2`, where (in this example) the numbers match up, I want to have a list of the corresponding letters as tuples.
I would like to use `findall/3` and only one predicate for this.

I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55611334/1243762) here before on how to solve something similar, where the answer was using two predicates. That solution looked like this:

```
find_item((Val1,Val2)):-
    fact1(A, _, Val1, _, _),
    fact2(_, A, Val2, _, _).`

test(Items) :-
    findall(Item,find_item(Item),Items).
```

The result for the given example of facts, should look like this:

```
[(a, b),  (c, c),  (f, e)]
```

Can the two predicates be combined using just [findall/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3)?

Comment: I changed the title so that others could easily find this and learn from it. While your title was correct, it was too specific and other might pass it by even though it would have what they needed.

Comment: Alright thank you. Looks like I have plenty to learn not only in prolog but in SO too.

Comment: Note that, depending on the Prolog system, using control constructs (e.g. conjunctions, disjunctions, if-then-else, ...) in the `findall/3` goal argument can result in performance penalties.

Comment: @PauloMoura Your note carries more weight to be just a comment. If it were me I would add it as an additional answer. Many people don't read comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *inline* procedure `find_item/1` as the goal of [`findall/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3) (use a conjunction of goals instead of a single goal):

```
test(Items):-
  findall((Val1, Val2), (fact1(A, _, Val1, _, _), fact2(_, A, Val2, _, _)), Items).
```